# Meaning of "Complx" as notation

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

In [this article](https://academic.oup.com/gji/article/128/2/345/727012/Three-dimensional-massively-parallel) one can find the following expression on Appendix B (typos also transcribed):

$$
z_k = \mathcal{Re}\sum_{j = 1}^{N}\text{Complx}(D_{jj}y_j, D_{j + N\;j+n}y_{j + n})^*\times\text{Complx}(A_{jk}, A_{j+N\;k}),
$$
where $^*$ stands for complex conjugation.

What does $\text{Complx}(D_{jj}y_j, D_{j + N\;j+n}y_{j + n})$ stand for?

Does it stand for the complex number $z_k$ defined by $D_{jj}y_j$ as its real part and $D_{j + N\;j+n}y_{j + n}$ as its imaginary part?

Googling "Complx" did not really help, and I have never encountered such notation before... It seems like a constructor for complex numbers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the paragraph right before the first occurrence of the expression implies that $\mathrm{Complx}(a,b)=a+bi$.

> ... **the vector $\mathbf{y}$ is real with
>   dimension $2N$**, where $N$ is the number of complex data points
>   used in the inversion. ... For
>   compact programmable expressions, **we let the vector $\mathbf{y}$ ... be redefined as complex** so that they can be
>   conveniently stored in the computer memory. ... we have for the $j$th element of
>   the first matrix-vector multiplication
>   $$y_j=\mathrm{Complx}\Bigl\{\cdots\Bigr\}$$
>
> ([***original text***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2TIr.png))

Comment: I don't really see how to redefine this as complex makes it "programmable"... I am still reading the entire thing :)

Comment: As a more interesting comment, a question: Why would they just get the real part out of the equation? Shouldn't the expression yield a real value without being forced to be real? It stills baffles me why they just take the real part by simply saying: "$z_k$  must be real". Although, when analysis harmonic signals, the real part foes have its meaning...